# Sqlite Android Optimization

Tags: java, android, sqlite, view, query-optimization

I have an application that works well. But I suspect that I can improve it if I optimize queries to the database. And I need suggestions.

This is part of my "select query":

```
private static final String SELECT = "SELECT " +
        "dz.first_id AS first_id, " +
        "dz._id AS _id, " +
        "dz.att1 AS att1, " +
        "dz.att2 AS att2, " +
        "dz.att3 AS att3, " +
        "dz.att4 AS att4, " +
        "dz.att5 AS att5, " +
        "d.var1 AS var1, " +
        "d.name AS name, " +
        "d.last_update AS last_update, " +
        "d.image_url AS image_url, " +
        "d.image_highlighted_url AS image_highlighted_url, " +
        "d.var2 AS var2, " +
        "d.type AS type, " +
        "d.state AS state, " +
        "d.sync AS sync, " +
        "d.var3 AS var3 " +
        "FROM table1 dz INNER JOIN table2 d " +
        "ON d._id = dz.first_id ";

Cursor result = conn.rawQuery(SELECT, null);
```

*`table1` and `table2` have simple creation: only one `_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`

It is useful to use views? Any other suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for query optimizations? Be specific. Also, can you post your table schema?

Comment: Indexing the WHERE and the JOIN is a life saver. But also using StringBuilders in place of string concatenations.

Comment: Im looking for query optimizarions yes. The tables creation is simple, only one _id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL

Comment: Is there an actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

This query looks as cut and dry and they can get, I think your options are really either to see if you can somehow leave some unnecessary columns out of your select or alternatively to see that both dz.first_id and d._id have indexes setup. Perhaps add a index to dz with the following

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON table1 (first_id);
```

Comment: Without this query, the DB will scan `table1` and look up the matching rows in `table2` using the rowid (`_id`), which is faster than using a separate index, so I doubt this will change anything.